# Creating dynamically a finite n-dimensional coordinate system with integer coordinates from axial coordinates

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, dynamic, dimensions

I'm trying to dynamically create a list of locations in a finite n-dimensional coordinate system by first creating the axial coordinates. The system only has integers as coordinate values. The axial coordinates are AxCrd-objects. A AxCrd-object has two properties:

1. AxCrd.dim is the handle or name of the dimension of the coordinate. For example, "x" or "y".
2. AxCrd.crd is the value of the coordinate. It's an integer. For example, -4 or 3.

I've tried to write a function that'd accept all the generated AxCrd objects as input and would output a list of all positions in the n-dimensional space I'm trying to create as Crd-objects. A Crd-object has two properties:

1. Crd.dims is an array containing all the dimension handles of the coordinates. The length of this array is n, that is, equal to the amount of dimensions.
2. Crd.crds is an array containing all the coordinate values of aforementioned dimensions. The ordering of this array matters, because the dimension of a coordinate is supposed to have the same element number as the coordinate value. Ie. if dimension "z" is the 2nd element, then crds[2] is the coordinate value for dimension "z".

For example, suppose I use these constructor functions:

```
function AxCrd(dim,crd) { this.dim = dim, this.crd = crd }
function Crd(dims,crds) { this.dims = dims, this.crds = crds }
```

In my actual intended use, most of the dimensions have nine values: four negative, four positive and one zero. But for brevity, let's suppose I have three dimensions so that:

```
var input = [];
input.push(new AxCrd("x", -1));
input.push(new AxCrd("x", 1));
input.push(new AxCrd("y", -1));
input.push(new AxCrd("y", 1));
input.push(new AxCrd("z", -1));
input.push(new AxCrd("z", 1));
input.push(new AxCrd("d", -1));
input.push(new AxCrd("d", 1));
```

As you can see, there are three dimensions and each one of them has only two coordinate values. I'm trying to write a function that, given the above input, would create new Crd objects like this:

```
var ret = [];
ret.push(new Crd(["x","y","z","d"],[-1,-1,-1,-1]));
ret.push(new Crd(["x","y","z","d"],[ 1,-1,-1,-1]));
ret.push(new Crd(["x","y","z","d"],[-1, 1,-1,-1]));
ret.push(new Crd(["x","y","z","d"],[ 1, 1,-1,-1]));
ret.push(new Crd(["x","y","z","d"],[-1,-1, 1,-1]));
ret.push(new Crd(["x","y","z","d"],[ 1,-1, 1,-1]));
ret.push(new Crd(["x","y","z","d"],[-1, 1, 1,-1]));
ret.push(new Crd(["x","y","z","d"],[ 1, 1, 1,-1]));
ret.push(new Crd(["x","y","z","d"],[-1,-1,-1, 1]));
ret.push(new Crd(["x","y","z","d"],[ 1,-1,-1, 1]));
ret.push(new Crd(["x","y","z","d"],[-1, 1,-1, 1]));
ret.push(new Crd(["x","y","z","d"],[ 1, 1,-1, 1]));
ret.push(new Crd(["x","y","z","d"],[-1,-1, 1, 1]));
ret.push(new Crd(["x","y","z","d"],[ 1,-1, 1, 1]));
ret.push(new Crd(["x","y","z","d"],[-1, 1, 1, 1]));
ret.push(new Crd(["x","y","z","d"],[ 1, 1, 1, 1]));
```

How do I do this for an n-dimensional space?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you need a map for all dimension names to their indeces (call it `dim_map` should be `dim_map['x'] = 0; dim_map['y'] = 1;...`).
Then when you do the conversion you use the keys as as `dims`, lookup the index of `index = dim_map[AxCrd.dim]`  and assign that values to the respective element (`Crd.crds[index] = AxCrd.crd`).

I'm not fully sure this is what you want since your examples seem confusing. I'm not sure I get why you construct two Crds for every AxCrd or why some of the other values seem to change.

Comment: In the "game" or artificial intelligence I'm creating, each of the coordinates is supposed to have a "moral value". You might want to think of it as "score". That is, a player gets a certain score by moving, or being moved, to a certain coordinate. I want to precalculate these scores so that it's easier to write code for a computer for finding the best move. I intend to add the precalculated score as a property of the Crd-object.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion seems the right way to handle this kind of problems. Here is a simple recursive function that returns the array of the points as a result. It also stores the names of dimensions in an array passed as function parameter.

```
function rec(i, input, dimensions)
{
   // find the name of the current dimension
   var currentd = input[i].dim;

   dimensions.push(currentd);

   // find how many elements in the current dimension
   var j = i;
   while (j < input.length && input[j].dim == currentd) ++j;

   // create a tail of results
   var tail = [];
   if (j < input.length) {
      tail = rec(j, input, dimensions);
   }

   // create a result by appending tail to all possible coordinates in the current dimension
   var result = [];
   for (; i < j; i++) {
       if (tail.length == 0) {
           result.push([input[i].crd]);
       } else {
           for (var k = 0; k < tail.length; k++) {
               result.push([input[i].crd].concat(tail[k]));
           }
       }
   }
   return result;
}
```

This function does not create `Crd` objects as such, but you can easily modify it do to so. Usage example:

```
var dimensions = [];
var result = rec(0, input, dimensions);
console.log(JSON.stringify(dimensions));
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result[i]));
}
```

Output (assuming `input` is as in your example):

```
["x","y","z","d"]
[-1,-1,-1,-1]
[-1,-1,-1,1]
[-1,-1,1,-1]
[-1,-1,1,1]
[-1,1,-1,-1]
[-1,1,-1,1]
[-1,1,1,-1]
[-1,1,1,1]
[1,-1,-1,-1]
[1,-1,-1,1]
[1,-1,1,-1]
[1,-1,1,1]
[1,1,-1,-1]
[1,1,-1,1]
[1,1,1,-1]
[1,1,1,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you were looking for all possible combinations of the items of each subarray, or the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). This can be calculated recursively:

```
function product(array) {
    if (array.length == 0) return [[]];

    var head = array[0];
    var tail = product(array.slice(1));
    var res = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < head.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < tail.length; j++) {
            res.push([head[i]].concat(tail[j]));
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Ans use it like this:

```
var input = [
    [-1, 1],    // x
    [-1, 1],    // y
    [-1, 1],    // z
    [-1, 1],    // d
];

var prod = product(input);

for (var i = 0; i < prod.length; i++) {
    console.log(i, prod[i]);
}
```

The above function works under the assumption that the passed array is an array of arrays. No attempt is made to detect that.

Instead of printing, you can add the resulting arrays to your list. I'm not sure why you create a new coordinate system every time you add a coordinate. Shouldn't you create the coordinate system only once and pass a reference to that? I also second Sorin in that you probably want a map for dimension-by-letter lookup. Your class design seems unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 0):

What I intend to do seems to be almost achieved by the following function:

```
function makeAllCoordinates(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) { return []; }
  else if (arr.length === 1) { return arr[0]; }
  else {
    var result = [];
    var allCases = makeAllCoordinates(arr.slice(1));
    for (var c in allCases) {
      for (var i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
        result.push((arr[0][i] + allCases[c]).split(",")); }}
    return result; }}
```

The result is an array of 9 × 9 × 9 × 9 × 3 × 3 = 59049 members. This number is correct. However, the each array only has one member, which is a string consisting of six repetitions of "[object Object]". I need them to be unique arrays of six AxCrd-objects instead of such strings. The order of the array doesn't matter. Is it difficult to modify this function that way?

In any case, I hope this reply clears ambiguity regarding what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Maybe if you consider the results as arrays, not strings: `result.push([arr[0][i]].concat(allCases[c]));`? When you posted this answer, two other answers had already posted more or less the same code. If you just want to clarify things, edit the original question. SO allows you to anser your own questions, but only if they are genuine and unique solutions.